# How would you send HTTP request during computer startup?

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop-computer

I need to send HTTP request (to REST API without any additional data) during startup of my computer. The sooner the better. But it can't be sent later than the appearance of Windows login screen. For now I'm looking more for a software solution rather than hardware one.

Of course, using hardware would probably be easier here as I could have just simply connect ESP8266 (or some similar board) for example and when it would get powered it could automatically send a HTTP request, but I don't like to overpay, so I would probably buy it from China and wait 2 months to get it from there as I don't have any free arduino-like board right now. And also why should I complicate things, when there may be some simple solution, right?

Edit: Oh, sorry, I forgot to put Windows version (did that in tags however). I'm using Windows 10 feature update 1803. I have sockets connected to my WiFi and they power up my monitors and speakers. I need them to turn on, when I power up my computer, so I need to call REST API for that. Simple HTTP request without need to send any additional data.
Also the call goes to local ip address, so I don't need DNS service.

Comment: Can you provide more information like what system you are powering up, Windows version, etc.?  What are you trying to accomplish (locate the system, alert a remote system of the reboot?)  More information will help people understand your problem and help provide additional information.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to put Windows version (did that in tags however). I'm using Windows 10 feature update 1803. I have sockets connected to my WiFi and they power up my monitors and speakers. I need them to turn on, when I power up my computer, so I need to call REST API for that. Simple HTTP request without need to send any additional data.

Comment: You could run a batch file on startup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218346/run-batch-file-on-start-up

Comment: But this will run after logging in right? If so, it's too late.

Comment: I’m curious. Other than trying to see if you can do this and to tinker, why would you not just put a power strip on all those devices and have the PC turn on automatically after power loss. One switch and done.

Comment: PC must have power entire time as I'm using Wake On LAN.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the script to the Startup scripts of the local Group Policy, then it will run during the Startup process. First enter "edit group policy" in the search box at the bottom left of Windows 10 to open the Local Group Policy Editor.

**Local Group Policy Editor->Computer Configuration->Windows Setting->Scripts(Startup/Shutdown)**

Right click on the "Startup" displayed in the right window and click on "Properties". Then click "Add" in the new window to add the script.

Comment: Well, this still starts the script too late - script runs after log on, while I want for it to start before logging in, which I stated in the question.

Comment: Scripts(Startup/Shutdown) in computer configuration will run as soon as computer is powered on/off. Scripts(Logon/Logoff) in user configuration only run after user log on/off to the system. You can refer to this article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/556007      Maybe your script needs to run for a little long time and it's finished until the user logs on.

Comment: Well, you're kinda right - it finally runs, but it takes about 17 seconds, which is unacceptable. I tried using curl and python, both solutions were too slow (although I think it's rather because of Windows running it too late as both scripts can send a request in, I don't know, less than 1s?)